How can I play non-ranked games to try out new decks?
When experimenting with new decks, I like to try them out against other seasoned players doing the same thing, rather than playing ranked matches (and very likely losing miserably until everything is fine-tuned).
However, the training mode works very poorly for this purpose nowadays. Match-making rank clearly does not apply to training mode, because I keep getting paired with clueless day 1 newbies who don't even know the basics. All of them playing the same old Nilfgaard starter deck. Newbies are obviously not even a half-decent test of how well my deck is doing. I even know every single card they have.
How can I test out new decks in non-ranked standard matches?

There’s apparently a casual mode. I don’t know how helpful it would be for purposes.

@Daemons Where can find that?
